# Use joined field as variable for date_sub

Tags: mysql

I have the following query;

```
SELECT count(*) as aggregate 
FROM cars
INNER JOIN snapshots ON cars.snapshot_id=snapshots.id
WHERE cars.snapshot_id=194340
```

That works correctly - counting all cars with a specific snapshot_id.

But now I want to only count cars who have been there for greater than 1 hour from when the snapshot was created.

I've tried this - but it doesnt work:

```
SELECT count(*) as aggregate 
FROM cars
INNER JOIN snapshots ON cars.snapshot_id=snapshots.id
WHERE cars.snapshot_id=194340
AND time_arrive_destination <= DATE_SUB('snapshots.created_at', INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

I know I'm close - because if I hard code the timestamp from `snapshots.created_at` - it works:

```
SELECT count(*) as aggregate 
FROM cars
INNER JOIN snapshots ON cars.snapshot_id=snapshots.id
WHERE cars.snapshot_id=194340
AND time_arrive_destination <= DATE_SUB("2015-08-31 20:29:49", INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

So how do I use a joined column field `snapshots.created_at` as a variable for `date_sub()`?

Comment: is `time_arrive_destination` a column?

Comment: yes - it should probably read `cars.time_arrive_destination`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need (or want) to escape an identifier (e.g. a column name, because it's a reserved word), enclose the identifier in backtick characters, not single quotes, e.g.

```
AND time_arrive_destination <= DATE_SUB(`snapshots`.`created_at`, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```